# How to tell Google to not send EXECUTE intents for sensor?

Tags: actions-on-google

**EDIT** The bug in the validator was fixed however there are still on/off buttons in the Home App which trigger EXECUTE events

I have a [Switch](https://developers.google.com/assistant/smarthome/guides/switch) with a [OnOff](https://developers.google.com/assistant/smarthome/traits/onoff) trait and want to tell Google to not send any EXECUTE intents. According to the device [attributes](https://developers.google.com/assistant/smarthome/traits/onoff#device-attributes) I can set `queryOnlyOnOff` to true but when I try doing that the validator tells me: `data.payload.devices[1].attributes.queryOnlyOnOff is not a valid key`.

Here's my SYNC response:

```
    "requestId": "12519994412830690644",
    "payload": {
        "agentUserId": "0c3760df-3e43-4522-b1c2-16d1c4ca8b04",
        "devices": [
            {
                "id": "dev0",
                "type": "action.devices.types.SENSOR",
                "traits": [
                    "action.devices.traits.OnOff"
                ],
                "attributes": {
                    "commandOnlyOnOff": false,
                    "queryOnlyOnOff": true
                },
                "name": {
                    "name": "device1"
                },
                "willReportState": true
            },
            {
                "id": "dev1",
                "type": "action.devices.types.SWITCH",
                "traits": [
                    "action.devices.traits.OnOff"
                ],
                "attributes": {
                    "commandOnlyOnOff": true,
                    "queryOnlyOnOff": true
                },
                "name": {
                    "name": "device2"
                },
                "willReportState": true
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: This appears to be a bug in the validator which doesn't validate that field. It should be fixed.

Comment: It still gives this error to me

Comment: The key has been added to the validator, although it is now warning that you can't include both `commandOnly` and `queryOnly`. They're mutually exclusive.

Comment: I can confirm the validator now correctly validates this request: https://hasteb.in/qitilase.json but there is still a button in the app that can be clicked to send EXECUTE intents

Comment: Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: @MichaelRittmeister looks like your hasteb.in link has expired. Please verify that you don't have both `commandOnly` and `queryOnly` set to true in your SYNC response.